# How can I pass a button's id to an Angular function?

Tags: angular, typescript, function, backend, comments

I'm working on a website (basically a twitter clone), and I want to add comments to posts. To do so, I have to pass the ID of the tweet and the comment itself to the backend. So far I have the following code:

```
toggle(event: Event): void {
    let elementId: string = (event.target as Element).tagName;
    console.log(elementId);
    this.commentModel.value.ID = elementID;
  }
```

This gets called in the HTML as follows:

```
 <form [formGroup]="homepageservice.commentModel"
                    class="container d-flex row rounded-pill p-2 justify-content-between align-items-center w-80 addCommentBox"
                    id="add-comment" (submit)="onSendComment()">
                    <textarea type="text" name="comment" class="rounded-pill col" id="comment-input"
                        formControlName="commentcontent" placeholder="Write comment here...."></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" name={{tweet.ID}} id="addComment" class="btn btn-green rounded-pill"
                        (onclick)="homepageservice.toggle($event)">
                        <i class="bi bi-send-fill"></i>
                    </button>
                </form>
```

Lastly the form and the sending function:

```
commentModel = this.fb.group({
commentcontent: [''],
id: [''] }) 

sendComment() {
const commentText = this.commentModel.value.commentcontent;
const id = this.commentModel.value.ID;
return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + `/Tweets/newComment? 
comment=${commentText}&tweetID=${id}`, {}); }
```

When I run these, I get an undefined ID, and can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
showing the problem.
You can use [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com) to create a MRE.

The good part about making a MRE is that you might end up finding the problem yourself ;)
 And in case you don't, people can use the MRE to check where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this: `(click)="homepageservice.toggle(tweet)"`
and in your service:

```js
toggle(tweet: any) {
    console.log(tweet);
    this.commentModel.value.ID = tweet.ID;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was overthinking the problem. This is an easy, and great working solution!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try pass an ID parameter like this?

```
<button type="submit" name={{tweet.ID}} id="addComment" class="btn btn-green rounded-pill"
                        (onclick)="sendComment(tweet.ID, $event)">
                        <i class="bi bi-send-fill"></i>
                    </button>
```